# Constructor in Angular automatically creates an object?

Tags: javascript, angular, constructor

I found some weird behavior that if I declare variable with a type of the class and without initialization. I can't access methods of this class, this for sure right.

BUT if I declare variable in constructor also without initialization,
then I can use methods of this class.

This behavior only at Angular, I tried the same thing at TS, it didn't 'work.

I only can explain it for myself, that Angular autmaticle initializes values inside constructor, am I right? Check code

In my code I just trying to get wrong url, and then to handle error

This is an error :

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'handle')
>
> at ProductsService.errorHandler

Code:

```
export class ProductsService {
    //this initialization  will work
    constructor(private http: HttpClient, private errorService: ErrorService) {
    }

    getProducts(): Observable<Iproduct[]>{
        return this.http.get<Iproduct[]>('https://fakestoreapi.com/productsp',{
            params: new HttpParams().append('limit', '8')
        })
        .pipe(
            tap((value) => console.log(value)), 
            delay(2000),
            catchError(this.errorHandler.bind(this))
        );

    }
    // no problem to call the method
    private errorHandler(error: HttpErrorResponse){
        this.errorService.handle(error.message);
        return throwError(() =>error.message);
    }
}

// this leads to error 
export class ProductsService{
    //different decloration of the variable  errorService
    private errorService: ErrorService 
    //like this will work when manually initialize
    //private errorService: ErrorService = new ErrorService()
    constructor(private http: HttpClient,){
        
    }

    getProducts(): Observable<Iproduct[]>{
        return this.http.get<Iproduct[]>('https://fakestoreapi.com/productsp',{
            params: new HttpParams().append('limit', '8')
        })
        .pipe(
            tap((value) => console.log(value)), 
            delay(2000),
            catchError(this.errorHandler.bind(this))
        );

    }

    private errorHandler(error: HttpErrorResponse){
        //method not defined
        this.errorService.handle(error.message);
        return throwError(() =>error.message);
    }

}
```

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are experiencing the [dependency injection pattern](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection) which Angular embrasses.

> Dependency injection, or DI, is one of the fundamental concepts in
> Angular. DI is wired into the Angular framework and allows classes
> with Angular decorators, such as Components, Directives, Pipes, and
> Injectables, to configure dependencies that they need.
>
> Two main roles exist in the DI system: dependency consumer and
> dependency provider.
>
> Angular facilitates the interaction between dependency consumers and
> dependency providers using an abstraction called Injector. When a
> dependency is requested, the injector checks its registry to see if
> there is an instance already available there. If not, a new instance
> is created and stored in the registry. Angular creates an
> application-wide injector (also known as "root" injector) during the
> application bootstrap process, as well as any other injectors as
> needed. In most cases you don't need to manually create injectors, but
> you should know that there is a layer that connects providers and
> consumers.

Comment: So happy to meet it!